# "this" function with parameter

Tags: javascript

I've got a class Robot as defined below. But for some reason there's an error with the processCommand function and I can't figure out what it is. It's the only function that takes a parameter so I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the way I pass it in the readCommands function?

Any help or opinion is appreciated!

```
function Robot(pos){
this.pos = pos;
this.language;

this.printCoords = function(){}

this.setLanguage = function() {}

this.setPos = function() {}

this.processCommand = function(s){

    var direction = this.pos[2];
    direction = direction.replace(" ", "");

    if( (s.match('V') && this.language.match("svenska")) ||
        (s.match('L') && this.language.match("engelska")) ){
            switch(direction){
                case "N":
                    // Look West
                    this.pos[2] = " W";
                    break;
                case "E":
                    // Look North
                    this.pos[2] = " N";
                    break;
                case "S":
                    // Look East
                    this.pos[2] = " E";
                    break;
                case "W":
                    // Look South
                    this.pos[2] = " S";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }       
    }
    else if( (s.match('H') && this.language.match("svenska")) ||
             (s.match('R') && this.language.match("engelska")) ){
                switch(direction){
                case "N":
                    // Look East
                    this.pos[2] = " E";
                    break;
                case "E":
                    // Look South
                    this.pos[2] = " S";
                    break;
                case "S":
                    // Look West
                    this.pos[2] = " W";
                    break;
                case "W":
                    // Look North
                    this.pos[2] = " N";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }       
    }
    else if( (s.match('G') && this.language.match("svenska")) ||
             (s.match('F') && this.language.match("engelska"))){
            switch(direction){
                case "N":
                    // Walk North
                    this.pos[1] += 1;
                    break;
                case "E":
                    // Walk East
                    this.pos[0] += 1;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    // Walk South
                    this.pos[1] -= 1;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    // Walk West
                    this.pos[0] -= 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }           
    }
    this.printCoords();
}

this.readCommands = function() {
    document.getElementById("textField").onkeyup = function(key){

        key = window.event;
        keyCode = key.keyCode || key.which;
        if(keyCode == '13'){
            var commandString = document.getElementById("textField").value;

            for(var i = 0; i < commandString.length; i++){
                this.processCommand(commandString[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please, set up a fiddle demo.

Comment: Also please update us with the error that you are talking about

Comment: it's the onkeyup event stealing "this". dupe it to that or self or something and point to that in the event handler.

Comment: How are you instantiating `Robot`?

Comment: I believe the 'this' inside of your processCommand function is referring to the processComand function itself, not to the 'this' outside of that function. I believe javascript's bind method can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @niiru No. `this` inside a function refers to the context, which is going to be the instance of `Robot`, not the `processCommand` method itself.

Comment: Also, you aren't setting `language` to a string anywhere, which means it won't have a `.match` method.

Comment: What's the error, and where do you set `language`?

Comment: If I put an alert statement as the line before the processCommand call in readCommands and as the first line in the processCommand function the first alert is shown but not the second so there's probably something wrong with the way I pass the variable right?

@Asad Robot is instantiated like this:
    var wall_e = new Robot([0,0," N"]);
I've changed so language is assigned an empty string but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: How/When do you call `readCommands`? If it's only called once, the answers you got should work (not sure why someone downvoted them all). But if it's called multiple times, you'll be attaching multiple keyup handlers (once per keystroke), and you have to fix that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your event handler, (`function(key){}`) isn't doing what you want it to do.

This is because in the context of an event handler invocation, `this` usually refers to the DOM element on which the event occurred, not the instance of `Robot`.

Try this code instead:

```
this.readCommands = function() {
    var that = this;

    document.getElementById("textField").onkeyup = function(key){

        key = window.event;
        keyCode = key.keyCode || key.which;
        if(keyCode == '13'){
            var commandString = document.getElementById("textField").value;

            for(var i = 0; i < commandString.length; i++){
                that.processCommand(commandString[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you store a reference to the actual object you want to call the method `processCommand()` on, and can invoke it in the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

using the old that=this trick:

```
function Robot(pos){
this.pos = pos;
this.language;

this.printCoords = function(){}

this.setLanguage = function() {}

this.setPos = function() {}


this.processCommand = function(s){

    var direction = this.pos[2];
    direction = direction.replace(" ", "");

    if( (s.match('V') && this.language.match("svenska")) ||
        (s.match('L') && this.language.match("engelska")) ){
            switch(direction){
                case "N":
                    // Look West
                    this.pos[2] = " W";
                    break;
                case "E":
                    // Look North
                    this.pos[2] = " N";
                    break;
                case "S":
                    // Look East
                    this.pos[2] = " E";
                    break;
                case "W":
                    // Look South
                    this.pos[2] = " S";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }       
    }
    else if( (s.match('H') && this.language.match("svenska")) ||
             (s.match('R') && this.language.match("engelska")) ){
                switch(direction){
                case "N":
                    // Look East
                    this.pos[2] = " E";
                    break;
                case "E":
                    // Look South
                    this.pos[2] = " S";
                    break;
                case "S":
                    // Look West
                    this.pos[2] = " W";
                    break;
                case "W":
                    // Look North
                    this.pos[2] = " N";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }       
    }
    else if( (s.match('G') && this.language.match("svenska")) ||
             (s.match('F') && this.language.match("engelska"))){
            switch(direction){
                case "N":
                    // Walk North
                    this.pos[1] += 1;
                    break;
                case "E":
                    // Walk East
                    this.pos[0] += 1;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    // Walk South
                    this.pos[1] -= 1;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    // Walk West
                    this.pos[0] -= 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }           
    }
    this.printCoords();
}

var that=this;

this.readCommands = function() {
    document.getElementById("textField").onkeyup = function(key){

        key = window.event;
        keyCode = key.keyCode || key.which;
        if(keyCode == '13'){
            var commandString = document.getElementById("textField").value;

            for(var i = 0; i < commandString.length; i++){
                that.processCommand(commandString[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's a lot of code to quickly glance at and surmise an answer. But, `this` errors are typically a result of `this` not having the value you think it should.

It's important to recognize that the value of `this` changes based on the calling context of the function. A typical solution to solve errors like this is to store the value of `this` in a variable that can be referenced later, i.e.;

```
var self = this;
```

and then use `self` instead of `this` directly.